# 'Manage to' as a catenative verb construction

Tags: grammar, catenative-verbs

I've only started my own studies on grammar recently and as I was reading CoGEL by Randolph Quirk, I came across this category called 'Catenative verb constructions'. According to the analysis used in the book, catenative verb constructions cannot be interpreted as verbs followed by a nonfinite clause acting as a direct or prepositional object. However, '*manage to*' is also included yet when I look up the dictionary, '*manage*' can be transitive even when used with the meaning 'to succeed in doing something, especially something difficult' like in these examples:

> *In spite of his disappointment, he managed a weak smile.*

> *I don't know exactly how we'll manage it, but we will, somehow.*

Shouldn't 'manage to' be listed elsewhere then ? Or am I misinterpreting something ?

Comment: Dictionaries and grammars are two different things. Expecting them to agree, or be organized along the same lines is a recipe for frustration. Various grammars don't even agree on the proper categorization for items like these, so why would one expect a certain dictionary's listings to reflect a particular grammar's categories?

Comment: In your example, "a weak smile" and "it" are objects of "managed". "Manage to" is not a verb; it's just manage that is the verb,; the "to" is part of the clause that is complement of "manage". "Manage" is only a catenative verb when it has a _to_- infinitival clause as complement, as in "I managed [to find my wallet]". Note that non-finite clauses do not function as objects.

Comment: Lots of catenative words can be used in non-catenative senses, e.g. "try" is catenative in "He tried to open the door" but not in "He tried the fish".

Comment: 'He helped wash up'/'He helped to wash up' // 'He helped us to wash up' //// 'He helped all of us.'

Comment: *to* is not part of *manage to*; it’s the particle of whatever *to*-infinitive will follow *manage*: *He managed [to attempt] [to smile].* (In traditional grammar, the infinitives function like direct objects — He managed what? To attempt. He attempted what? To smile.)

Comment: Welp, I guess it's really difficult to neatly organize every single grammatical items into categories. Still quite a brain exercise, though. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3):

If we use the old-school definition of **transitive** as "taking a direct object" then *He managed a smile*  could be regarded as transitive. To paraphrase the meaning: He *produced* a smile. Making an effort to remain in control of his face, he smiled, though he didn't really feel like smiling.

But *manage* can be complemented by a non-finite clause, similar to **want** and **try**.

> He wanted to smile and tried smiling but the trip to the dentist had left his jaw in too much pain for him to manage a smile.

Or

> ... in too much pain for him to manage to smile.

A verb needn't fall into one or the other category *exclusively*.

Answer (score 1):

*Manage (to)* is an [Implicative](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/presuptrig.pdf) verb, semantically.

It entails its [A-Equi](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) complement clause, and presupposes some effort on the part of the agent subject of *manage*.

- *He managed to open the door, and it creaked loudly*.
- **He managed to open the door, but it wouldn't budge*
- **He managed to open the door by waving his hand*